# Error converting Turbo Pascal to C++ code

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi, turbo-pascal

here is a working Turbo Pascal example

```
uses graph, crt;
const xmax=600;
      ymax=400;
type vreal=array[1..xmax] of real;

var
   y:vreal;
   r,h,vmax,vmin,a,b:real;
   i,linie0:integer;
   grDriver: Integer;
   grMode: Integer;
   s:string;
   c:char;
{****************************************}
procedure regimgrafic;
begin
  grDriver := Detect;
  InitGraph(grDriver, grMode,'');
  setcolor(15);
end;
{****************************************}
function f(x:real):real;
 begin
f:=exp(cos(2*x)*ln(x))+3*sin(x);
 end;
{**************************************************************}
procedure calcul(a,b:real;var z:vreal);
begin
  h:=abs(b-a)/(xmax-1);
  for i:=1 to xmax do z[i]:=f(a+(i-1)*h);
end;
{**************************************************************}
procedure normare(var z:vreal; var l0:integer;var vmax,vmin:real);
var
 delta,deplasare:real;
begin
 vmax:=z[1];vmin:=z[1];
 for i:=2 to xmax do
  begin
     if z[i]>vmax then vmax:=z[i];
     if z[i]<vmin then vmin:=z[i];
  end;
      delta:=(vmax - vmin)/(ymax);
      deplasare:=0-vmin;
      l0:=round(ymax-deplasare/delta);
      if vmin>0 then l0:=415;
      if vmax<0 then l0:=10;
  for i:=1 to xmax do
      z[i]:=ymax-(z[i]+deplasare)/delta;
end;
{*******************************************************}
procedure axax(linie0:integer);
begin
 setcolor(11);
 outtextxy(getmaxx-15,linie0-10,'X');
 line(20,linie0, getmaxx-20,linie0);
 h:=(b-a)/2;
 for i:=0 to 2 do
   begin
    fillellipse(20+i*300,linie0,2,2);
    r:=a+i*h;
    str(r:0:2,s);
    outtextxy(20+i*290,linie0+10,s);
   end;
end;

procedure axay;
begin
 setcolor(14);
 outtextxy(10,10,'Y');
  h:=(vmax-vmin);
 for i:=0 to 1 do
   begin
    fillellipse(20,10+i*400,2,2);
    r:=vmax-i*h;
    str(r:0:2,s);
    outtextxy(20,10+i*400,s);
   end;
 line(20,10,20,getmaxy-65);
end;

procedure modeleazagrafic(y:vreal);
begin
 rectangle(1,1,getmaxx,getmaxy);
 setcolor(11);
 axay;
 axax(linie0);
 for i:=1 to xmax do putpixel(i+20,10+round(y[i]),15);
 outtextxy(20,460,'Alt interval (D)a / (N)u');
end;

begin
repeat
clrscr;
write('Introdu extremitatile intervalului: ');
readln(a,b);
calcul(a,b,y);
normare(y,linie0,vmax,vmin);
regimgrafic;
modeleazagrafic(y);
c:=readkey;
closegraph;
until upcase(c)='N';
end.
```

and here is my c code

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

const int xmax = 600;
      int ymax = 400;

typedef float vreal[600];

using namespace std;

vreal y;
  float  r,h,vmax,vmin,a,b;
  int linie0;
  int  grDriver;
  int grMode;
  string s;
  char c;



void regimgrafic()
{
initwindow(xmax,ymax,"COOL");
setcolor(WHITE);
}


float f(float x)
{
 return exp(cos(2*x)+log(x)+3*sin(x));      
}

void calcul(float a, float b,float* z)
{
      h = fabs(b-a)/(xmax-1);
      for(int i=1;i <=  xmax;i++)
      {
              z[i] = f(a+(i-1)*h);
      }
}

void normare(float *z, int* l0, float *vmin, float *vmax)
{
 float delta, deplasare;

 *vmax = z[1];
 *vmin = z[1];    
     for(int i=2;i<= xmax;i++)
     {
     if(z[i] > *vmax) *vmax = z[i];
     if(z[i] < *vmin) *vmin = z[i];       
     }
   delta = (*vmax - *vmin)/(ymax);
   deplasare = 0-*vmin;
   *l0 = (int)(round(ymax - deplasare/delta));

   //<static_cast><int>()
   if((*vmin)>0) l0 = 415;
   if(*vmax<0) l0 = 10;
   for(int i=1;i<= xmax;i++)
    z[i]=ymax - (z[i]+deplasare)/delta; 
}     

void axax(int linie0)
{
 setcolor(11);
 outtextxy(getmaxx-15,linie0-10,'X');
 line(20,linie0,getmaxx-20,linie0)
 h=(b-a)/2;
 for(int i =0;i<2;i++)
 {
   fillellipse(20,10+i*400,2,2);
   r=vmax-i*h;      
   sprintf(s, "%d", r);
   outtextxy(20+i*290,linie0+10,s);
}     

}


void axay
{
     setcolor(14);
     outtextxy(10,10,'Y');
     h=(vmax-vmin);
     for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
     {
      fillellipse(20,10+i*400,2,2);
      r=vmax-i*h;
      sprintf(s,r);
      outtextxy(20,10+i*400,s);             
     }
}     

void modeleazagrafic(vreal y){
rectangle(1,1,getmaxx,getmaxy);
 setcolor(11);
 axay;
 axax(linie0);
 for(int i=1;i<xmax;i++)
      putpixel(i+20,10+round(y[i]),15);
     outtextxy(20,460,'Alt interval (D)a / (N)u');
}     


int main()
{
do {    
printf("Introduceti extremitatile intervalului: ");
scanf("%f %f",&a,&b);
calcul(a,b,y);
normare(y,linie0,vmax,vmin);
regimgrafic;
modeleazagrafic(y);
c=getch();
closegraph();
}while(toupper(c) == 'N');

}
```

I've got a bunch of error, here is some of thementer code here

```
Line 60:(in normare function) invalid conversion from `int' to `int*' 
line:61 the same error;
line:69 69 pointer to a function used in arithmetic
```

please help to fix those error

Comment: Don't use a typedef for the array.  Use `std::vector`, since you tagged as C++.

Comment: C != C++. Pick the one you're actually using for the tags, and don't just grab things that have nothing to do with the question you're asking.

Comment: In C and C++, arrays begin with an index of 0.

Comment: `l0` is an `int*` but you're trying to assign `415` to it. Perhaps you meant `*l0 = 415` instead. For the second error, I'm guessing `getmaxx` is a function, therefore you should change it to `getmaxx()`.

Comment: l0 is a pointer (i.e. its value is an address), what is  if((*vmin)>0) l0 = 415; supposed to do? I guess you intended to write *l0 = 415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost like you're not reading the error messages or thinking about the surrounding code.

Those first two relate to these lines:

```
if((*vmin)>0) l0 = 415;
if(*vmax<0) l0 = 10;
```

Everywhere else in that function, `l0` (which is of type `int*`) is correctly dereferenced during assignment.  But here you are forgetting to.  You need to use `*l0`, not `l0`.  The error is because you are trying to assign an `int` to a pointer (`int*`), as the error message quite explicitly states.

The other error is not so obvious, because your code does not show a variable, function or macro named `getmaxx`...  But judging by the error message, it seems that the identifier `getmaxx` refers to a function.  Perhaps you meant `getmaxx()`, assuming it has no parameters and returns a value.  Presumably you have the same problem with `getmaxy` elsewhere in your code.

Please get in the habit of reading error messages and examining the line of code it refers to.  Then think about what it means, and try to take hints from other parts of the code (or even other C programs).  If you are not familiar with C, this is a useful way to learn.

Comment: I believe the confusion stems from the fact that in the Pascal code, parentheses are not needed for function calls without a parameter list (I don't know Pascal, I'm just guessing.)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, but only realised after scanning through the Pascal program to see that is indeed how such functions are called.  I haven't programmed in Pascal for over 15 years.  Looks like we both followed the general advice to work things out by looking at the surrounding code =)

Comment: right there is not getmaxx without brackets ,str(r:0:2,s); is C or C++ will lock like what ?

Comment: @user3254845 I don't understand what you're trying to ask there.  Do you know any Pascal, C or C++?

Comment: yeah, I'm asking what is the equivalent for pascal instruction str(r:0:2,s); in C or C++ ?

Comment: What does that instruction *do*?

Comment: convert  integer value to string

Comment: There are resources all over the web, as well as on StackOverflow, for doing this in both C and C++.  While I could simply dump some code on you, I think it would be more helpful to get you to do your research.  It's not a difficult operation, but you need to make an effort.

Comment: I've solve that problem,buff = sprintf(s,"%d",r);
      outtextxy(20,10+i*400,s);

Comment: Uhhhm, you really can't call `sprintf` on a `std::string`.  And `r` is a `float`, not an `int`.